# Strange establish connection problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
application_controller 

   def database_changer
    Item.establish_connection(
        :adapter  => current_product.db_config.adapter,
        :host     => current_product.db_config.host,
        :username => current_product.db_config.username,
        :password => current_product.db_config.password,
        :database => current_product.db_config.database
    )
    end
```

When a user chooses a product, it sets session[:product_id] and call database_changer for this product. My question is when another user chooses another product, it is effecting other user too. For example:

> User A signs in and chooses Product X.
>   User B signs in too and he chooses
>   Product Y. And now User A refreshs his
>   page and see Product Y's items

How this is happening ?

Answer (score 0):

The database connection is expected to be the same for the class across the app regardless of app/request/session.

A better way to do this would be to sub-class Item for each different database source you have and then figure out which sub-class to use.

Comment: Thanks sir. All database configurations are dynamically created and stored in database. I can't use database.yml. When a product is created, its database is automatically created. I couldnt find a way to do this.

Comment: The point that i dont understand is how come they affect their database connections. Users are switching to their connection. What is establish connection doing ? What is its scope. Is it affecting all application?